# Anyone else missing min/max/close buttons on firefox ubuntu 21.10? They still work, they are just not visible

Tags: firefox, 21.10, titlebar, window-buttons

Anyone else missing min/max/close buttons on firefox ubuntu 21.10? They still work, they are just not visible.

Here I am hovering over the close button:

[image: Here I am hovering over the close button]

It’s been this way for months across multiple versions and I can't work out why.

Comment: Are you running (or have you recently run) a different Gnome theme? 

Comment: yeah, yaru. I think adwaita is the default

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you.

The switches are placed under: *Tweaks* -> *Window Titlebars* -> *Titlebar Buttons*.

[image: Screenshot of Tweaks preferences section showing "Maximize/Minimize" settings.]